# Ruby on Rails: Exclude Elements from Arrray

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a beginner so much of the following is probably incorrect/not optimal, but so far it works! I'm learning but one thing I can't figure out how to do is:

I have a set of images. These are @fsets. I want to display one image from the set in a field of 3, but ensure there are no duplicates. So if I have an array of [image1, image2, image3, image4] a user can pick image2 and have it show up with 2 others selected from the remaining images. In my controller I have:

```
  def rotator
    @fset = Fset.find(params[:id])    
    @image = Exemplar.find(params[:image])    
    @setdistractora = @fset.line_items.sample
    @setdistractorb = @fset.line_items.sample
  end
```

The first line finds the set based on the :id in the url.
The second finds the selected image based on the :image parameter passed in the url.
The third and fourth line take two random images from that same set as the other two images.

This is what I wrote first to get things started but I'm sure there is a better way to do things. To try and solve the no-repeat image problem I tried:

```
 @remainingset = @fset - @image
 @setdistractora = @fset.line_items.sample
 @setdistractorb = @fset.line_items.sample
```

That didn't work...so I tried

```
 @remainingset = [@fset] - [@image]
```

which returns an array but I can't use the line_items association to call the images.

Can anyone help with this? Thank you!

****** EDIT 1 ******

to add relationships

```
class Exemplar < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader  
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :fsets, through: :line_items

class Fset < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :fset
  belongs_to :exemplar
```

****** EDIT 2 ******

Well...I solved my issue although there is probably a better way to do it. Here is what I changed.

To Fset class I added a has_many through:

```
 class Fset < ActiveRecord::Base  
      has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :exemplars, through: :line_items
```

This cleaned up a lot of my views and made them more readable and also allowed me to do this in the controller:

```
@fset = Fset.find(params[:id])    
@image = Exemplar.find(params[:image])    
@subset = @fset.exemplars - [@image]
  @setdistractora = @subset.sample
@subsetb = @subset - [@setdistractora]
  @setdistractorb = @subsetb.sample
```

So now in my view:

```
<div class="rotate">            
<%= image_tag @image.image_url(:thumb) %>
</div>

<div class="rotate">        
<%= image_tag @setdistractora.image_url(:thumb) %>                          
</div>  

<div class="rotate">            
<%= image_tag @setdistractorb.image_url(:thumb) %>                          
</div>
```

So each image is now unique and random. Thank you for the responses below as they helped get me thinking about where I could go to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@fset` is an array, correct?

You can subtract arrays from arrays as so:

```
[4,3,2,1] - [2] # -> [4,3,1]
```

So it should be:

```
@remainingset = @fset - [@image]
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the reply but when I do that it gives me the error saying that `undefined method '-' for #<Fset:0x00000104c1f138>`

Comment: Sounds like @fset is not an array. How can you access the array of images? `@fset.images`? However you can get the array of images, do that and then subtract the `[@image]`
If that doesn't help, then could you paste the Fset and Image models and their relationship?

Comment: And if I do `@remainingset = [@fset] - [@image]` it says `undefined method 'line_items' for #<Array:0x00000109b75a70>`

Comment: Oh I think I see where I'm making the mistake - @fset is the object? And the array is called when it's `@fset.line_items` - so I have to subtract from there?

Comment: If you're removing just one thing, `delete` usually does the job.

Comment: But delete returns the element that you've deleted, and in this case he wants to return the resulting array. He could also do: `@fset.images.reject { |a| a.id == @image.id }` but that's even more verbose.

Comment: Does it delete it from the array permanently? These sets of images are user created and I only want to exclude certain images from a set of three for presentation purposes.